# Math: Converting minutes and seconds to a percentage between 0 and 1

Tags: objective-c, math

So I want to make a UIProgressTimer show the right progress from 0 to 1. And I want this to synchronize with a timer I have which is in minutes and seconds. So my idea was first to combine the minute and seconds by dividing seconds by 100. So that if `minutes` is 29 and `seconds` is 59 I get a float with the number `29.59`.

And then divide this by the duration, so if the duration is 30.  `29.59 / 30 = 0.9863`. but here is the problem, since i use seconds, when dividing by the duration it get´s wrong. How can I make this work properly? I am a lousy mathematician.

```
 if ([dict isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {
        NSNumber *minute = [dict objectForKey:@"minute"];
        NSNumber *second = [dict objectForKey:@"second"];
        NSNumber *duration= [dict objectForKey:@"duration"];


        float combined = [minute floatValue] + ([second floatValue] / 100);
        [self.progressView setProgress:combined / [duration floatValue] animated:NO];
```

Answer (score 1):

Ah... stupid, it´s just to change this line (100 with 60)

```
float combined = [minute floatValue] + ([second floatValue] / 60);
```